# Is there a way to pickle a custom tensorflow.keras metric?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, metrics

I defined the following custom metric to train my model in `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as ks
N_CLASSES = 15

class MulticlassMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    def __init__(self,
                 y_true = None,
                 y_pred = None,
                 num_classes = None,
                 name = "Multi_MeanIoU",
                 dtype = None):
        super(MulticlassMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,
                                             name = name, dtype = dtype)
        self.__name__ = name

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config, "num_classes": self.num_classes}

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis = -1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

met = MulticlassMeanIoU(num_classes = N_CLASSES)
```

After training the model, I save the model and I also tried to save the custom object as follows:

```
with open("/some/path/custom_metrics.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(met, f)
```

However, when I try to load the metric like this:

```
with open(path_custom_metrics, "rb") as f:
    met = pickle.load(f)
```

I always get some errors, e.g.  `AttributeError: 'MulticlassMeanIoU' object has no attribute 'update_state_fn'`.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to pickle a custom metric at all and if so, how? It would come in handy if I could save custom metrics with the model, so when I load the model in another Python session, I always have the metric which is required to load the model in the first place. It would be possible to define the metric anew through inserting the full code to the other script before loading the model, however, I think this would be bad style and could cause problems in case I would change something about the metric in the training script and forget to copy the code to the other script.

Comment: This will not solve your problem, and I am facing the same issue here, but:
When creating a custom keras object, you need to decorate it with `keras.utils.register_keras_serializable` to tell keras to register it. Otherwise, you will end up getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to `pickle` a metric, one possible solution is to use `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods. During the (de)serialization process, these two methods are called, if they are available. Add these methods to your code and you will have what you need. I tried to make it as general as possible, so that it works for any `Metric`:

```
    def __getstate__(self):
        variables = {v.name: v.numpy() for v in self.variables}
        state = {
            name: variables[var.name]
            for name, var in self._unconditional_dependency_names.items()
            if isinstance(var, tf.Variable)}
        state['name'] = self.name
        state['num_classes'] = self.num_classes
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state: Dict[str, Any]):
        self.__init__(name=state.pop('name'), num_classes=state.pop('num_classes'))
        for name, value in state.items():
            self._unconditional_dependency_names[name].assign(value)
```

Comment: Adding this results in ```AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'name'``` when I change nothing else

Comment: Fixed it. It should only get `tf.Variable`s and not other parameters. It works for a few metrics that I checked. Let me know if you found any exceptions.

Comment: In my case, it says 
```File "c:\users\manuel\python\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py", line 2807, in __init__
    target_class_ids = list(range(num_classes))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer``` when I try to unpickle the metric...

Comment: `num_classes` is a variable that is not saved as `tf.Variable`. Modified the code to account for it. If you have other variables that are not accounted for, add them to the state definition for save and then use them when loading in a similar fashion.

Comment: Apparently, this solution works. But I had to change ```Dict[str, Any]``` to ```dict[str, any]``` (because of the capital letters, Python expected some variable). Also, I have to define an empty class like ```class MulticlassMeanIoU: pass``` before being able to load the actual metric due to ```AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MulticlassMeanIoU' on <module '__main__'>```

Comment: I used Python 3.8, which uses `Dict` for type annotation. Later versions use `dict` which is more convenient. You may remove all type annotations. Also, as I said on my first comment, if you use `@keras.utils.register_keras_serializable` to decorate your class, keras will register it in its list of objects and later can load it without the need to create an empty class.