# Image segmentation with class weights in TensorFlow.Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

**Background**
I am training models for semantic segmentation in TensorFlow. Currently, I am running the training with grayscale ground truth images, i.e. 1 channel where each integer value encodes a class. In this setup, I was able to introduce sample weights according to [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation), where I could simply pass weights like this to model.fit: `model.fit(dataset["train"].map(add_sample_weights))`. Here, 3 tensors with shapes [batchsize, 512, 512, 3], [batchsize, 512, 512, 1], and [batchsize, 512, 512, 1] are passed to `model.fit`, where the first one is the 3-channel RGB image, the second one contains class integers and the last one contains class weights.

**Problem**
However, I wanted to monitor mean IoU instead of `val_loss` or `val_accuracy`. The models have one-hot-encoded output while the ground truth data has 1 channel, which means I had to wrap the `tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU` in a new class where I applied `tf.math.argmax` to the model output in order to make it fit the expected input of the `mIoU` metric. The resulting function causes me a lot of trouble (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72793439/how-to-make-custom-metric-available-for-callbacks) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646236/is-there-a-way-to-pickle-a-custom-tensorflow-keras-metric)).

**Question**
Now, I decided it would be easiest to use `tf.one_hot` on the ground truth images in the image data loader, so I can use the `tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU` out of the box. How do I have to change the weights then?

In the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) it mentioned that the weights were some tensors of similar shape to the ground truth data. Now that I one-hot encoded the ground truth images, how do I have to change the weights? Does `tf.Keras` now expect me to also one-hot encode the weights, or does it simply take a list containing the weights?